Proof of Ostrogradsky's Formula-- Integration of rational functions
Ostrogradsky method is in general formula $$\int \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}+\int \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx$$
Where $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is a simplest rational function; $q(x)$ is a polynomial with all the roots in $Q(x)$ but with only multiplicity $1$. $Q_1(x)=\frac{Q(x)}{q(x)}$
I would like to ask, how to prove this formula?
Given that $$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^l\sum_{k=1}^{k_j}\left(\frac{a_{jk}}{(x-x_j)^k}\right)+\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{m_j}\frac{b_{jk}x+c_{jk}}{(x^2+p_jx+q_j)^k}$$
Where $p(x)$ is a polynomial that only occurs when $\deg P(x)\ge \deg Q(x)$, and $a_{jk},b_{jk},c_{jk}$ are uniquely determined real numbers. and
$$Q(x)=(x-x_1)^{k_1}\cdots (x-x_l)^{k_l}(x^2+p_1x+q_1)^{m_1}\cdots (x^2+p_n x+q_n)^{m_n}$$
This is a problem from Zorich's Mathematical Analysis Differentiation chapter that I could not solve, and it is from the section antiderivatives.
I have tried using the algebra formula given, but it doesn't seem to work.

There is a polynomial $p(x)$ mentioned in your second paragraph (starting with "Given that..."). Is this the same $p(x)$ that appears in the first paragraph? In the second paragraph $p(x)$ is never used.

I'm also doubtful about the formula in the first paragraph. The first term, in my understanding, is supposed to be the algebraic part, and the second term, the transcendental part. But if you try it for $\int\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^3},dx$, the formula suggests that the algebraic part is (proportional to) $\frac{x-1}{x^2}$. I don't think that is the case.

Looking at the source, I think your definitions of $p(x)$ and $P_1(x)$ are not correct. The analogous definitions do hold for $q(x)$ and $Q_1(x)$, but $p(x)$ and $P_1(x)$ must then be determined using partial fractions.

@WillOrrick I see, thank you very much. But can you cite a link of relevent resources for me? It would be really helpful.

@WillOrrick I checked the source again, it didn't describe $P(x)$ and $p(x)$. It  must be a misunderstanding on my part I think.

First recall that

$n>1$
$$\int\frac{dx}{(x-a)^n}=-\frac{1}{n-1}\frac{1}{(x+a)^{n-1}}+C$$
is also rational.
If $p^2-4q<0$, for $m>1$ the primitive
$$I_m=\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+px+q)^m}$$
satisfies the relation
$$I_m=\frac{1}{2(m-1)\big(q-\frac{p^2}{4}\big)}\frac{x+\frac{p^2}{2}}{(x^2+px+q)^{m-1}}+\frac{2m-3}{2(m-1)\big(q-\frac{p^2}{4}\big)}I_{m-1}
$$
Now, if $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is a proper fraction and
$$Q(x)=(x-a_1)^{\alpha_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-a_n)^{\alpha_n}(x^2+p_1x+q_1)^{\beta_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot(x^2+p_k+q_k)^{\beta_k}$$
where $a_j\in\mathbb{R}$, for $1\leq j\leq n$, $p_, q_j\in\mathbb{R}$, $p^2-2q_j<0$, for $1\leq j\leq k$, then
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum^n_{j=1}\sum^{\alpha_j}_{\ell=1}\frac{A_{j,\ell}}{(x-a_j)^{\ell}} + \sum^l_{j=1}\sum^{\beta_j}_{\ell=1}\frac{M_{j,\ell}x+N_{j,\ell}}{(x^2+p_jx+q_j)^{\ell}}$$
where $A_{j,\ell}\in\mathbb{R}$, $1\leq j\leq n$, $1\leq \ell\leq \alpha_j$, $M_{j,\ell}, N_{j,\ell}\in\mathbb{R}$, $1\leq j\leq k$, $1\leq \ell\leq \beta_j$.

The linearity of the antiderivative operator $\int
$ along with (1) and (2) yields
\begin{align}\int\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\,dx& =\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}+\int\left(\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{A_j}{(x-a_j)}+\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{M_jx+N_j}{x^2+p_jx+q_j}\right)\,dx\\
&=\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}+\int\frac{P_2(x)}{Q_2(x)}\,dx\tag{*}\label{one}
\end{align}
where
$$Q_1(x)=(x-a_1)^{\alpha_1-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-a_n)^{\alpha_n-1}(x^2+p_1x+q_1)^{\beta_1-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot(x^2+p_k+q_k)^{\beta_k-1},
$$
$$Q_2(x)=(x-a_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-a_n)(x^2+p_1x+q_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x^2+p_k+q_k),
$$
and $P_j$ ($j=1,2$) are either polynomials of degree at most $\operatorname{deg}(Q_j)-1$, or the $0$ polynomial.
Equation \eqref{one} implies that
\begin{align}
\frac{P}{Q}&=\left(\frac{P_1}{Q_1}\right)'+\frac{P_2}{Q_2}\\
&=\frac{P'_1Q_1-P_1Q'_1}{Q^2_1}+\frac{P_2}{Q_2}
\end{align}
Observe that $Q=Q_1Q_2$, $Q'=Q_1S$ for some polynomial $S$, for if $z$ is a root of $Q$ of multiplicity $\lambda$, then $z$ is a root of $Q'$ of multiplicity $\lambda-1$. Then $Q_1S=Q'_1Q_2+Q_1Q'_2$ and so $Q_1$ divides $Q'_1Q_2$. Therefore
$$\frac{P'_1Q_1-P_1Q'_1}{Q^2_1}=\frac{P'_1Q_2-P_1R}{Q_1Q_2}$$
for some polynomial $R=\frac{Q'_1Q_2}{Q_1}$, and $\frac{P'_1Q_2-P_1R}{Q_1Q_2}$ is a proper fraction.
Putting things together, we obtain that
$$\frac{P}{Q}=\frac{P'_1Q_2-P_1R}{Q}+\frac{P_2}{Q_2}$$
It follows that
$$P=P'_1Q_2-P_1R+P_2Q_1$$
Since $P$ is a polynomial of degree at most $\operatorname{deg}(Q)-1$, by gathering coefficients of same peers of $x$, one obtains a linear system of $\operatorname{deg}(Q)$ equations and
$\operatorname{deg}(Q)$ unkowns.
As given polynomial $Q$,  the polynomials  $P_1$ and $P_2$ exists satisfying \eqref{one} for every $P$ of degree at most $\operatorname{deg}-1$ for every polynomial, the system linear system has unique solution, i.e., the determinant of the system is not zero.
I hope this shows the OP  how and why the method of Ostogradsky works.

Here is a concrete example. Also an exercise in Zorin's textbook:
$$
\begin{align}
P(x)&=2 x^6+3 x^5+6 x^4+6 x^3+10 x^2+3 x+2 \\
Q(x)&=x^7+3 x^6+5 x^5+7 x^4+7 x^3+5 x^2+3 x+1
\end{align}
$$
$$Q'(x)=7x^6+18x^5+25x^4+28x^3+21x^2+10x+3$$
One can use a symbolic language (Maxima, Mathematica, Mapple, etc) to get the greatest common divisor between $Q$ and $Q'$ (if doing it by hand, use the Euclidean algorith; it took me 3 steps) to get that
$$Q_2(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1)$$
$$Q_1(x)=x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2(x^2+1)$$
Putting things together, one has
$$\int\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\,dx=\frac{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}{x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1}+\int\frac{kx^2+\ell x+ m}{x^3+x^2+x+1}\,dx
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\frac{2 x^6+3 x^5+6 x^4+6 x^3+10 x^2+3 x+2}{x^7+3 x^6+5 x^5+7 x^4+7 x^3+5 x^2+3 x+1}&=\partial_x\left(\frac{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}{x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1}\right)+\\
&\qquad \frac{kx^2+\ell x+ m}{x^3+x^2+x+1}\\
&=-\frac{-c + 2 d - 2 b x + c x + 2 d x - 3 a x^2 + c x^2 + 4 d x^2 - a x^3 + 3 c x^3 - a x^4 + 2 b x^4 + a x^5}{(1 + x)^3 (1 + x^2)^2}+\\
&\qquad \qquad \frac{kx^2+\ell x+ m}{x^3+x^2+x+1}
\end{align}
That is
\begin{align}
2 x^6+3 x^5+6 x^4+6 x^3+10 x^2+3 x+2 &= k x^6+ (\ell +2k-a) x^5 + (a-2b+2k+2\ell+m)x^4+\\
&\quad (2m+2k+2\ell-3c+a)x^3+\\
&\quad(2m+2\ell+k-4d-c+3a)x^2+\\
&\quad (2m+\ell-2d-c+2b)x + c-2d+m
\end{align}
This yields the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0& 0\\
2 & 2& 1 & 1& -2 & 0&0 \\
2 & 2& 2& 1 & 0& -3&0\\
1&2&2&3&0&-1&-4\\
0& 1& 2& 0 &2 &-1 &-2\\
0& 0& 1 &0 &0&1&-2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
k\\ \ell \\m \\ a\\ b\\ c\\ c
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\3\\6\\6\\10\\3\\2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has (unique) solution
\begin{align}
k=2,\, \ell= \frac12\,m =\frac12\, a=\frac32\,
b=\frac12\, c=\frac12\, d=-\frac12
\end{align}
Putting things together, we have that
$$
\int\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\,dx=\frac{\frac32 x^3 + \frac12 x^2+\frac12x-\frac12}{x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1}+\int\frac{2x^2+\frac12 x+\frac12}{x^3+x^2+x+1}\,dx
$$
